# Best possible way to extract data from news web API in 'Near Real Time' on Big Data Platform

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, apache-nifi

I have an use case, where in the first step is ingestion of data from news API's or news aggregator API's , into HDFS. This data fetch is to be done on a NRT basis(say every 15 mins) 
Presently I am working on 2 approaches:

1. Python based solution.(For now, its not generic code).
2. Apache NiFi based framework.(But NiFi seems to have some compatibility issues on other distributions other than Hortonworks)

It would be great to have few more suggestions for an approach which would be platform independent and could be used across different Hadoop Distributions(Cloudera,HW etc).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Apache NiFi can definitely handle your process, and it works well on Windows, MacOS, and most Linux distributions (I've run it on Ubuntu, Redhat, CentOS, Amazon Linux, and Raspbian).  It doesn't need Hadoop but can work with either Hortonworks or Cloudera Hadoop distributions.

I built an RSS viewer with NiFi that fetched, extracted, and saved RSS to disk using [GetHTTP](http://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.3.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.GetHTTP/index.html) -> [TransformXML](http://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.3.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.TransformXml/index.html) -> [PutFile](http://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.3.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutFile/index.html). 
NiFi then listended for browser requests and returned the RSS as an HTML table using [HandleHttpRequest](http://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.3.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.HandleHttpRequest/index.html) -> [GetFile](http://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.3.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.GetFile/index.html) -> [TransformXML](http://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.3.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.TransformXml/index.html) -> [HandleHttpResponse](http://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.3.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.HandleHttpResponse/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We did test a NiFi Solution. One of the constraints we found was that the web api's can send information in any formats(json,xml etc). In such case, we intended to use an aggregator(converter) to have the data back in a consistent specified format only(lets say Json). Also there could be a case where the API response could be partial. So , we are in a process to implement a more robust system to eliminate these concerns as well. Do share your thoughts.